# Не могу обратиться к методу внутри класса. Python 3.12.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

```
class Parser_to_xml():

    def import_xml(xml_file):                   
        with open(xml_file, 'r') as f:          
            base_xml = f.read()         
        BASE = BeautifulSoup(base_xml, 'xml')   
        return BASE
                     
    def parse_xml(self):
        BASE = self.import_xml('base.xml')
        servers = BASE.find_all('server')
        print(servers)

Parser_to_xml.parse_xml()
```

> TypeError: Parser_to_xml.parse_xml() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: разве там print(servers) с правильной табуляцией?

Comment: Извиняюсь, исправил

Answer (score 6):

`self` - экземпляр класса, что бы он появился нужно сначала его создать, а затем вызывать метод.

```py
instance = Parser_to_xml()
instance.parse_xml()
```

[Self in python](https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/programming/self-variabe-python-examples)

[Different methods in python](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/)

Comment: Прошу более развернутый ответ и желательно на примере моего кода, буду благодарен
Я вроде понимаю , а вроде нет ) Не знаю как объяснить

Comment: Добавил ссылку на статью с подробным описанием.